# Creating RPM from current directory

Tags: repository, rpmbuild

I'm trying to create an rpm from local source. Is it possible to do compilation in a similar to what `pdebuild` does - just copy the local directory as the source and operate on that copy? Every time I do `rpmbuild -ba ...` it tries to unpack some archive in `RPMBUILD/SOURCE`, but I don't want to go that way.

Essentially I'd like to be able to just checkout the repository with the code, do `rpmbuild -ba application.spec` in that checkout directory and have it do the right thing... Is that possible?

Comment: Even now after years passed, you'd probable need to use `--define` to define the rpmbuild paths.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about a better way than the following:

```
rpmbuild -bs my_file.spec --define "_sourcedir $PWD"
```

For my own project, I'm always using a `Makefile` to define `make rpm` once and then just use it.

Answer (score 0):

The `%setup` macro in the spec file is what unpacks the source. Remove that, and your problem goes away, and you can do anything you'd like to fetch the source.